# How to access parent class variable in sub class?

Tags: java, inheritance, superclass

First up all I am new to Java and I am still learning it. I have created a subClass that overrides the methods from parentClass.
In the code below, I have to use the value of the variable C that is being assigned through scanner object. After debugging, I found that the value of the variable C becomes zero when it starts executing the If else block used in sub class. I have used getters and setters even though the parent class is not private and used super keyword to access the value of the variable from parent class. What is wrong with this code?

```
#Main method
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Main {


        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Salary s = new Salary();
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter a valid salary: ");
            s.c = scan.nextInt();
            scan.close();

            s.range(1000, 2000);

            Bonus b = new Bonus();
            b.range(10, 100);

        }
    }



#parent class
    public class Salary {

        int c;

        public void range(int a, int b){

            if((a+b)<c){
                System.out.println("Employee has average salary");
            }
            else if ((a+b)>c) {
                System.out.println("Employee is rich");
            }
        }

        public int getC() {
            return c;
        }

        public void setC(int c) {
            this.c = c;
        }

    }

#SubClass
public class Bonus extends Salary {

    @Override
    public void range(int a, int b) {

        if((a+b)>super.getC()){
            System.out.println("Employee is applicable for bonus");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Employee is poor");
        }

    }
```

I want to get the code to execute the else block written in the sub class. The value of c becomes zero when executing the code in the super class.

Comment: Are you confused by the fact that you have two instances? Your `Salary` instance and your `Bonus` instance are completely unrelated.

Comment: Quite confused. If I remove the else block and provide inputs that satisfy the if block in inherited class, it actually shows the correct output.

Comment: Beside the technical issue: accessing a parent class variable from a child class violates the mots important principle in OOP: *information hiding/encasulation*. You should not do this, neither directly nor through "getter" methods.

Answer (score 1):

First, Parentclass = Superclass, you meant subclass.

The problem in your example is that, even though, `Bonus` is a subclass of `Salary` and `Bonus` inherits `int c` from it's parent, they are two different instances.

So the `int c` field in the object `b` is never set to the value you read from the standard input, so it is 0.

Try

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Salary s = new Salary();
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter a valid salary: ");
  int input = scan.nextInt();
  s.c = input; 
  scan.close();
  s.range(1000, 2000);
  Bonus b = new Bonus();
  b.c = input;
  b.range(10, 100);
}
```

This should work, but note that this is not OOP and you should learn some more about OOP principles.

**EDIT**

I would use composition over inheritance, like you have the `Salary` and some kind of `BonusDecider` class.

This `BonusDecider` would a similar method as your `range()` from `Bonus` but it would get as parameter also the `Salary` and than you can access the input value via the getter.

Your main would look like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Salary s = new Salary();
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter a valid salary: ");
  int input = scan.nextInt();
  s.c = input; 
  scan.close();
  s.range(1000, 2000);
  BonusDecider b = new BonusDecider();
  b.range(10, 100, s);
}
```

In this case, you get rid of unnecessary inheritance. In OOP, we favor composition over inheritance.

Comment: How to access the sub class without creating an instance of it?

Comment: You cannot. This is not how it works. I'm not sure what is your goal, but try to remodel your solution.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Actually, I was trying to understand Inheritance concept. Yes, this example is not a proper one. I will think of a logical solution.

Answer (score -1):

First you should understand super class and parent class are same.
Then in class Salary you have create getter and setter for c. But c is not private. So either you don't need getter and setter for c or you should make it private.

Here's [a link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_encapsulation.htm). This will provide you a better idea about Encapsulation.